# QGIS crash when creating a new field

Tags: qgis

I have a line layer that has approx. 5,000 records (which is not a lot, right?) and I am trying to create a new field that would be filled using the 3 existing ones but depending on the 4.
After about 20 seconds, QGIS crashes.
I am attaching a picture.

[image: code used]

Comment: Hi, some tips: handle NULL values with coalesce() function, convert to string naziv_III values, and try with a clean profile. I think one or all of those are the problem.

Comment: Thx...I did it part by part...